# Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in phptemplate_init() with specific theme

Tags: theming, social-network

I installed the last Drupal 7 Stack from BitNami. It seems to work correctly with the default themes but when I switch to the twitter_bootstrap theme (7.x-2.x-dev at http://drupal.org/project/twitter_bootstrap ) the "Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in phptemplate_init()" appears.

I look at the phptemplate.engine file but can't pinpoint the issue at line 14 (**_include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file;_**)

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Handles integration of PHP templates with the Drupal theme system.
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_init().
 */
function phptemplate_init($template) {
  $file = dirname($template->filename) . '/template.php';
  if (file_exists($file)) {
    include_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/' . $file;
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function phptemplate_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $templates = drupal_find_theme_functions($existing, array($theme));
  $templates += drupal_find_theme_templates($existing, '.tpl.php', $path);
  return $templates;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indications to solve this issue are available at: http://drupal.org/node/1423518